# How to use two AST node in one rule in pmd?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, pmd

I want to write a custom `PMD` rule that uses two `AST` nodes.

My custom rule scans the source code to find mathematical operators.

I want my rule to find more than one operators from these

```
+,*,/, and -
```

in the same expression.

I have tried some solutions but they did not work, for example:

```
public class OperatorPrecednece extends AbstractJavaRule {

    Public Object visit(ASTMultiplicativeExpression node, Object data) {


        Object tvisi(ASTAdditiveExpression node2, Object data2){
        addViolation(data2, node2);


        }

        return super.visit(node, data);

    }
}
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I chose XPath instead of Java. Put this rule into your pmd ruleset configuration xml:

```
<rule name="MultipleOperatorsInExpression" language="java" message="More than one different operator used in expression" class="net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.rule.XPathRule">
  <properties>
    <property name="xpath">
      <value>
        <![CDATA[
//Expression[.//AdditiveExpression and .//MultiplicativeExpression]
        ]]>
      </value>
    </property>
  </properties>
</rule>
```

But it's not a complete solution yet... I'm looking into a possible pmd bug: looks like that an expression like `1+2-3+4` gets a single `AdditiveExpression:+` node instead of 3 distinct nodes with their respective operators, so detecting an expression that uses just + and - or just * and / will not be detected. But it will detect expressions with mixed additive and multiplicative operators.

I will update the answer if I figure this out, but I hope the rule is of some use.

Comment: Thaaaaaaanks aloooooot Hairy, detecting expressions with mixed additive and multiplicative operators is what I need.
I use this solution and it works  :-)

Comment: I have to write more rules, if I need more helping from you, can I ask you?

Comment: No problem! I follow pmd and other static-analysis related tags, so next time you pose a question about it, I'll see it.

Comment: Here's a tutorial on how to write XPath checks: https://web.archive.org/web/20150522015043/http://techtraits.com/programming/2011/11/05/custom-pmd-rules-using-xpath/

Answer (score 1):

I'm adding another answer, to illustrate how a similar thing can be made with the Java interface. This is untested code, but here's the general idea:

```
public class OperatorPrecednece extends AbstractJavaRule {

    private boolean additiveExpression = false;
    private boolean multiplicativeExpression = false;

    public Object visit(ASTMultiplicativeExpression node, Object data) {
        multiplicativeExpression = true;
        if (additiveExpression) {
            addViolation(data, node);
        }
        Object superVisit = super.visit(node, data);
        multiplicativeExpression = false;
        return superVisit;
    }

    public Object visit(ASTAdditiveExpression node, Object data) {
        additiveExpression = true;
        if (multiplicativeExpression) {
            addViolation(data, node);
        }
        Object superVisit = super.visit(node, data);
        additiveExpression = false;
        return superVisit;
    }

}
```

So, the visitor pattern traverses the AST, and when it reaches an ASTMultiplicativeExpression it sets a multiplicativeExpression flag, and then continues the traversal. If inside that traversal it reaches a ASTAdditiveExpression, the flag will be set, and the violation added. When you return from that traversal back to the ASTMultiplicativeExpression, the flag is unset. And the same for ASTAdditiveExpression and additiveExpression flag.